# ¿Cómo resuelvo el error "Undefined Index" en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, csv

hace poco  me estoy iniciando en laravel
y estoy tratando de subir un archivo Csv y guardar la información en la bd, estoy usando laravel 5.8 y tambien estoy usando laravel excel 3.1

Aquí mi código en el Import que genero

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\UsoSuelo;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class UsosSueloImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {

        return new UsoSuelo([
            'cod_pais'     => $row['cod_pais'],
            'nom_fundo'    => $row['nom_fundo'], 
            'cod_rodal'    => $row['cod_rodal'], 
            'ano_plantacion' => $row['ano_plantacion'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Por ahora solo quiero que se carguen y/o pueda mostrar todo en pantalla pero tengo el error `"Undefined index: cod_pais"` vi la documentación https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html y lo tengo prácticamente igual, he vuelto a hacer mi csv de prueba porque leí que podía ser un error del csv y sigo igual.
Espero que puedan brindarme su conocimiento sobre este tema, gracias de antemano

Aca el modelo:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UsoSuelo extends Model
{
    protected $table = "uso_suelos";

    protected $fillable = ['cod_pais','nom_fundo','cod_rodal','ano_plantacion'];
}
```

Comment: Hola Paz. ¿Puedes poner el modelo del UsoSuelo? Creo que no tiene definidos los campos/propiedades y es por eso que no encuentra el indice 'cod_pais'...

Comment: También sería útil ver un dump de la variable `$row` y cómo le asignas el valor a esa variable antes de pasársela a la función `model`.

Comment: Ahi subí el modelo

Answer (score 1):

A partir de php 7, usa el `null coalescing operator`

```
public function model(array $row)
{

    return new UsoSuelo([
        'cod_pais'     => $row['cod_pais'] ?? null,
        'nom_fundo'    => $row['nom_fundo'] ?? null, 
        'cod_rodal'    => $row['cod_rodal'] ?? null, 
        'ano_plantacion' => $row['ano_plantacion'] ?? null,
    ]);
}
```

Este operador evalúa la expresión a la izquierda y si no está definida o puede ser evaluada como nulo, aplica el valor de la derecha. Es el equivalente a hacer:

```
$variable = isset($otraVariable) ? $otraVariable : 'valor por defecto';
```

Decir que el problema no es por usar laravel en si mismo, sino que estás intentando acceder a un índice inexistente de un array.

Comment: Probé lo que me dijiste y bueno, ya no me sale el error pero sale el siguiente:
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'cod_pais' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `uso_suelos` (`cod_pais`, `nom_fundo`, `cod_rodal`, `ano_plantacion`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 2020-01-14 21:35:19, 2020-01-14 21:35:19)) ◀"

:(

Comment: @PazOjeda, se trata de otro error, parece que el proceso encargado de generar el array que pasas como argumento a la función model no está generando los campos necesarios para insertar en base de datos. Te recomendaría en este caso hacer una comprobación dentro del constructor de UsoSuelo, si se intenta asignar un valor null a cod_pais, lanza una excepción que puedas elevar hasta el controlador y mostrar un mensaje de error.

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo solucioné, como dije recien estoy empezando, e imprimí con dd si tomaba las variables, me di cuenta que estaba mal formateado el csv, las delimitaciones estaban por ";" por lo que de ahí estaba el origen del problema  mis delimitador era " , " :( gracias de todas maneras!